# How can I remove Ubuntu safely and get back everything to the previous state?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I had a Windows XP system with 4 partitions. 3 of them were empty. I installed Ubuntu like so:

1. I downloaded Ubuntu 10.04 ISO file.
2. I burned it to a CD.
3. I booted from that CD and installed Ubuntu on an empty partition.

Current situation:

- From inside Windows, Ubuntu partition(s) is(are) not visible in **My Computer**.
- But they are visible in **Disk Management**.
- When my computer starts, I see Ubuntu's boot loader in which Windows is the last option.
- I am able to login to both Ubuntu and Windows XP properly and use them.

But my work with Ubuntu is done and I want to remove it from my system completely. I have backed up my data files.

**How can I remove Ubuntu safely and retain my XP installation and not screw anything up?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [fixmbr](http://www.windows-faq.de/2009/03/23/fixmbr-fixboot/), at the windows repair console, to get the windows bootloader back. After you did this, you may format the ubuntu partition to ntfs/fat32, to use it with windows again.

Comment: I am part of a Windows domain and it is a work computer. I do not have the installation disc. Apart from contacting the IT dept, is there any way to start the recovery console?

Comment: Even if you don't have the CD, I found that you can use this - http://www.sysint.no/nedlasting/mbrfix.htm tool to fix the MBR. It can be run from within Windows, but I guess it is not recommended. @Michael.. thanks for the fixmbr link. Searching for it lead me to this :)